# spark GC time improvement just by turning on GC log print options

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection

My Spark job showed for a task, about 75% or higher GC time out of total run-time. It uses almost full CPU (about 85% by spark configuration) and memories. While following [this reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#serialized-rdd-storage) for spark tuning, I turned on the GC log print options by adding:
`spark.executor.extraJavaOptions = " -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark"`

As you can see, all options are about logging and diagnosis.
However, these options improved the runtime from 5 hours to 2 hours!

How can we explain this improvement?

[Update]

- With  `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` option only, 1 hr 23 min.
- With  `-XX:+UseG1GC` option only, 7+ hrs.

Comment: Is it consistent then?

Comment: @thebluephantom Yes, always consistent. at least I tried 4 times and all showed only 2 hours. Without them were all 5+ hours. I also tried `-XX:+UseG1GC` only case and it showed much worse result like 7+ hours.

Comment: Interesting. Not sure what to make of it.  So, omitting these means going back to 5+ hrs?

Comment: @thebluephantom. Yes, going back to 5+ hrs. pretty much consistent. I don't know how to check what made this change in GC.

Comment: Interesting to say the least